# addChild for uifigure components

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I'm trying to develop my first GUIs with `uifigure` (programmatically, not with `appdesigner` [but I have added it as a keyword since it is related]), and (as expected) I'm missing some of the extended features and widgets as provided by the [GUI Layout Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox) and the [Widgets Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66235-widgets-toolbox) for standard java figures.

Thus, I tried to change some widgets that I had developed to `uifigure`, and `uigridlayout` seems to be quite handy to replace the `uix.VBox` and `uix.HBox` from the GUI Layout Toolbox.

For standard java figures, assume I have a class `MyWidget` and a corresponding instance `mywidget` of it. `MyWidget` would be, finally, an ancestor of `matlab.ui.container.internal.UIContainer` which provides an `addChild` method which can be overriden to customize the behaviour of

```
  uicontrol(mywidget)
```

I'm looking for the same for `uifigure` components. Assume the follwing class derived from `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout`, which is the class of the result of a `uigridlayout` call.

```
classdef MyGrid < matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
    methods
        function self = MyGrid(varargin)
            self = self@matlab.ui.container.GridLayout(varargin{:});
        end
    end
    methods ( Access = protected )

        function addChild(self, child)
            disp('hooray');
            addChild@matlab.ui.container.GridLayout(self, child);
        end
    end
end
```

When I now initiate a `MyGrid` instance

```
g = MyGrid()
```

everything looks good:

```
g = 

  MyGrid with properties:

    RowHeight: {'1x'  '1x'}
    ColumnWidth: {'1x'  '1x'}
```

but adding a child to it does not call the `addChild` method:

```
>> uibutton(g)

ans = 

  Button (Button) with properties:

               Text: 'Button'
               Icon: ''
    ButtonPushedFcn: ''
           Position: [100 100 100 22]
```

Note: No output of `hooray` above. The `Parent` property is correct:

```
>> ans.Parent

ans = 

  MyGrid with properties:

      RowHeight: {'1x'  '1x'}
    ColumnWidth: {'1x'  '1x'}

  Show all properties
```

From this I guess that `addChild` is not the method used (at least by `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout`) to add a child.

Does anyone know the mechanism of adding a child to a container in an `uifigure` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't look there yesterday, but the code of `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout` has the (protected) method

```
function handleChildAdded(obj, childAdded)
    obj.processChildAdded(childAdded);

    obj.addChildLayoutPropChangedListener(childAdded);

    obj.updateImplicitGridSize('childAdded', childAdded);

    obj.updateLastCell('childAdded', childAdded);
end
```

The method `processChildAdded` might be better for my purposes, but is private. Anyway, `handleChildAdded` works:

```
classdef MyGrid < matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
    methods
        function self = MyGrid(varargin)
            self = self@matlab.ui.container.GridLayout(varargin{:});
        end
    end
    methods ( Access = protected )
        function handleChildAdded(self, child)
            disp('hooray');
            handleChildAdded@matlab.ui.container.GridLayout(self, child);
        end
    end
end
```

```
>> g=MyGrid();
>> uibutton(g);
hooray
```