# Deriving a class from matlab.ui.container.GridLayout

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am still playing around with the `uifigure` components. As I [explained yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758438/addchild-for-uifigure-components), I'm interested in understanding `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout` to eventually use it as a base for some widgets.

But I experience the following behaviour when I derive a class from `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout`, which I do not understand. I have tested this with R2019a (Linux) and R2019b (Win):

```
g = matlab.ui.container.GridLayout('Parent', uifigure()); b = uibutton(g)
```

[image]

In contrast, if I derive a class from `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout`

```
classdef MyGrid < matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
    methods
        function self = MyGrid ( varargin )
            self = self@matlab.ui.container.GridLayout( varargin {:} );
        end
    end
end
```

and use

```
g = MyGrid('Parent', uifigure()); b = uibutton(g)
```

I get an empty figure:

[image]

Can anyone explain this behaviour and/or knows a way to show the Button in the case of the derived class?

Here is some more information:

- By setting a breakpoint in `matlab.ui.container.GridLayout.handleChildAdded` I see that this function is called in the case of adding the button to the `MyGrid` instance
- The size of `MyGrid` increases when the button is added:

```
>> g = MyGrid('Parent', uifigure());
>> g.RowHeight = {};
>> g.ColumnWidth = {}

g = 

  MyGrid with properties:

      RowHeight: {}
    ColumnWidth: {}

  Show all properties

>> b = uibutton(g);
>> g

g = 

  MyGrid with properties:

      RowHeight: {'1x'}
    ColumnWidth: {'1x'}

  Show all properties
```

- The buttom's `Visible` property is `on`

```
>> b.Visible

ans =

    'on'
```

- The grid's `Visible` property is `on`, too:

```
>> g.Visible

ans =

    'on'
```

- The `Layout` property of the button is correct:

```
>> b.Layout

ans = 

  GridLayoutOptions with properties:

       Row: 1
    Column: 1
```

- The `Parent` properties are okay:

```
>> f = uifigure();
>> g = MyGrid('Parent', f);
>> b = uibutton(g);
>> b.Parent == g

ans =

  logical

   1

>> g.Parent == f

ans =

  logical

   1
```

- The `Children` properties are okay, too:

```
>> f.Children(1) == g

ans =

  logical

   1

>> g.Children(1) == b

ans =

  logical

   1
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't solve your problem. Next thing I would look at is if your subclass also inherits all the `events` of the `GridLayout`. If not then your subclass might miss the mechanism to handle the addition of components to it (as it seem to happen on your other linked question).

Comment: I have added some more information to my question, but I don't know if this helps. Everything looks like expected.

Comment: I would follow the creation of the `gridlayout` and the addition of a child object with the debugger in both the original and your custom class ... and try to see where it diverges. When following the original class, try to find out at which point the grid layout is rendered on screen, then compare to your class to see why this doesn't happen.

Comment: I have done this, at least to a certain depth. I don't see any differences, but I will research this further. I have filed this to Matlab staff, too. It looks like a bug to me, or at least some missing documentation.

Comment: Just a thought and untested: The GridLayout class has a protected method for `handleChildAdded`, which is inherited by your subclass and is fine except that the method invokes a number of private methods, e.g. `addChildLayoutPropChangedListener`, which are not inherited by your subclass. It may be that you need to make an explicit invocation of the GridLayout methods (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-invocation.html#bup3_yj-1)) which make calls to private methods. That is, redefine the protected methods and use their superclass invocation (@).